# How check if array is full and if not full add to it?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, if-statement

I've got array. I've got an `isFull` method, which checks if the array is full, but I don't know how to use this to check if it's full, then if it's not full add to the array, otherwise disregard the add call.

The array should take 10 elements and then not accept any more. After 10 elements, it should 'be full' and disregard any `addSpy` calls.

How would you implement this?

```
public class ConcreteSubject extends AbstractSubject {

    public int arySize;
    private int i = 0;

    private static AbstractSpy[] spies;

    public ConcreteSubject(int a) {
        arySize = a;
        spies = new AbstractSpy[a];
    }

    @Override
    public void addSpy(AbstractSpy spy) {
        if (spies.length < 10) {
            spies[i] = spy;
            System.out.println("spy added at index " + i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void isFull() {
        //1
        boolean b = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < spies.length; i++) {
            if (spies[i] == null) {
                b = true;
            }
        }

        if (!b) {
            System.out.println("Array is full");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Array not full");
        }
    }



    public class TestSpies {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ConcreteSubject cs = new ConcreteSubject(10);
            AbstractSpy spy = new ConcreteSpy();

            AbstractSpy[] spies = new AbstractSpy[10];

            cs.addSpy(spy);
            cs.addSpy(spy);
            cs.addSpy(spy);

            cs.isFull();

        }
    }
```

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: You probably want to change to `public boolean isFull()` so that you can call `if (!cs.isFull())` cs.addSpy(spy);`  Maybe throw an exception if you attempt to call `cs.addSpy()` when it's already full.  Also, a suggestion to use meaningful names `boolean isFull = false;`

Comment: In addSpy definition you can check whether the size of the array is full by comparing with maximum size of array (arySize in the class above) rather than comparing with 10. Also, you can use a static counter variable in this class which can be used to compare with max size of array (arySize) while adding. If that counter is less than or equal to max size, you can add to the array. You need to add 1 to that counter every time you add an element to the array.

Comment: Is this some sort of exercise where you're required to use an array? I ask because… why don't you use a `List<AbstractSpy>` which can just grow as needed?

Comment: The array can't exceed 10 spies and so once it has filled that's it. I want to check whether it is full or not and if it's not then add a spy. How do i do this? I though i'd be able to advance on the isFull method i have but i'm not sure.

Comment: Change the signature of isFull method to return a boolean. call the ```isFull``` method at the beginning of your addSpy method. something like: ```if isFull() return;```. Also add a ```break``` in isFull just after ```b = true```

Comment: Please pick one, and *only one* [indentation style](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) for all code used in a project (here, a question). Use that *one* style consistently throughout all of the code for a project. Doing so makes is *much* easier to read/maintain code. Not doing so results in the people reading it having to put out extra effort to help you. While there are many opinions on which indent style is the best style to use, the important thing is to *pick one and **use it consistently*** throughout a project.

Comment: Functions/methods should be called names which indicate what they do. A function/method that's named `isFull` should return a true/false value indicating if the thing you're testing for is true (and that's really all it should do). For example: A `isFoobar()` method should return a true/false value which indicates if the instance of the class is foobar'ed. As currently written, your `isFull` method is inaccurately named. It should be called something like `indicateIfFull`, because that's what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing it would be like that:

```
@Override
public void addSpy(AbstractSpy spy) {
  if (!isFull())
  {
    spies[i] = spy;
    System.out.println("spy added at index " + i);
    i++;
  }
}
```

To use that, you should change your `isFull` method to:

```
public boolean isFull() {


  for (int i = 0; i < spies.length; i++) {
     if (spies[i] == null) {
         return false;
     }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid it's not a good solution. Imagine you are passing `null`s so it's never full but eventually `spies[i]` will throw an exception when you reach `i >= spies.length`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but there are multiple issues with the code anyway. I just illustrated the usage of `isFull` method

Answer (score 3):

1. `spies.length < 10` isn't correct. It should be `spies.length > 0 && i < spies.length` to make sure that the following assignment `spies[i] = spy;` is always valid.
2. `void isFull()` should be `boolean isFull()`. Your implementation looks OK, just return `b`. `full` is a tricky word because technically an array is always "full". A better adjective would be `populated`, `filled`.
3. Since `addSpy` isn't filling null gaps but simply adds a spy to the end, `isFull` could be rewritten to `return spies.length == i;`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a track of the number of filled cells of the array using a variable. And before inserting anything into it, check if the filled cells count strictly less than the size of the array (obviously you want to keep track of the array total size as well).